# Unable to Create Intel based Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create an AVD in AVD manager based on Intel.

[image]

I have all Intel based required AVDs for API 23.

[image]

When I select API 23 in Target, CPU/ABI shows me only ARM based images, where it should show me ARM as well as Intel based images.

I want to use Intel HAXM to improve performance and without this AVD, i cant get that kind of performance.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

** Edit**

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the Intel HAXM driver in the extras at the bottom of the SDK manager? Otherwise, you could use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.

Comment: Problem is, though i have downloaded Intel based AVDs, it is not showing in AVD manager. It is only showing default AVDs and Google APIs.

Comment: the HAXM driver has its own installer that you need to install. also check your bios if virtualization is enabled

Comment: HAXM is installed from directory SDK/extra/intel/Hardware_Accelarated_Execution_Manager/   and virtualization is supported as well as enabled.

Comment: try using the new AVD manager from inside Android Studio

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Studio does allow AVD creation using Intel images. For some reasons, i need to work with Eclipse, can't use Studio. I just don't see them when creating AVDs using Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your views. Issue is solved. Just system restart was needed.